# Android: EditText content

Tags: android, android-edittext

)
I am having a bit of a problem with my app. I am using a multiline edit text.
I want its content to have a bit of a left space (not the edittext, but the text in it), because of a drawable i set as backgroud for the edittext.

Just like padding works for layout alignment, is there anything to align text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    <EditText
         .....
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
         .....
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a padding,

You can simply use `android:paddingLeft="20dp"`

or `android:padding="20dp"` for your EditText in your XML.(i don't know exactly what you want, just try).

If you want to align your text,

Try to use Android:Gravity in order to align your text in your EditText.

Here is the code : `android:gravity="right"` (in order to have right align for your text)

You can find more information about what you can do with this here : [Android Gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity)